# Windows 8 Consumer Preview doesn't boot off a DVD of GParted

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-8-preview, gparted

I have a Windows 8 Consumer Preview installation on my desktop computer. It's been running pretty well, except for a few issues that are not related by a long shot.

Until now. I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.04, so I tried to partition my hard drive. However, that didn't work because of where my files were located on the drive (see any drive mapping software). Naturally, I downloaded GParted and tried to use it to move the files. However, when I finally get my BIOS to boot off the DVD, it does not launch GParted; instead, it runs Windows 8 - just 50 times (yes, really) slower. **Everything** lags until I remove the DVD. Then, back to normal speed.

I am 115% puzzled by this. Why does this happen, and what can I do be able to launch GParted?

Comment: Did you rebooted or just shut down your windows 8? If you shut down it will not boot another system as you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shutdown in Windows 8 is really a form of hibernation, which means you will not get access to the bios functions on power up, it will post but goes directly to the hibernate file to boot up. They have done this to speed up boot times, a restart will not have this behavior, so to boot from a different source you should restart.

If you run this command from the command prompt it will invoke a full and complete shutdown.

> shutdown /s /full / t 0

.

> The key thing to remember though is that in a traditional shutdown, we close all of the user sessions, and in the kernel session we close services and devices to prepare for a complete shutdown.
>
> Now here’s the key difference for Windows 8: as in Windows 7, we close the user sessions, but instead of closing the kernel session, we hibernate it. Compared to a full hibernate, which includes a lot of memory pages in use by apps, session 0 hibernation data is much smaller, which takes substantially less time to write to disk. If you’re not familiar with hibernation, we’re effectively saving the system state and memory contents to a file on disk (hiberfil.sys) and then reading that back in on resume and restoring contents back to memory. Using this technique with boot gives us a significant advantage for boot times, since reading the hiberfile in and reinitializing drivers is much faster on most systems (30-70% faster on most systems we’ve tested).

[Detailed Explantion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8)

.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I'll try this. I had not heard of this.

Comment: You are welcome, this is gong to cause real headaches for users when W8 finally is sold on PCs late this year, oh what fun.